# how to generate 'create table script' using only tsql.I am using freeTDS tool in Linux machine to access sql server located at remote

Tags: sql-server, linux, t-sql, freetds

How to generate '`create table script`' using only `tsql` for all the tables in a database.

 Format of script should be same as we generate using Microsoft studio 2012

I am using `freeTDS` tool in Linux machine to access `sql server`.

Comment: you mean how to generate  table schema  automatically?

Comment: Yes .You are right. I want to generate 'create' query automatically  without using Microsoft studio.Please let me know if any other info required

Comment: Check [Is there a way to generate table create script in TSQL](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53085/is-there-a-way-to-generate-table-create-script-in-tsql)

Answer (score 2):

Try this tool that comes with FreeTDS defncopy

```
usage:  defncopy 
        [-U username] [-P password]
        [-S servername] [-D database]
        [-i input filename] [-o output filename]
        [owner.]object_name [[owner.]object_name...]
```

Example would be

```
defncopy  -S SERVERINSTANCE -U Username -P SomePass  -D '[NAME-OF-THE-DB]' '[schema].[Table]' > Table.sql
```

This will produce complete create statement along with statements for any constraints and indexes that are part of the table.